# Ant-Design React-Native Search Bar Cancel Button cannot hide itself when pressed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to make the Cancel button on the right of the search bar hide when it gets press. I tried to use to showCancelButton prop but it is not working. [Ant-Design React-Native Docs Link](https://rn.mobile.ant.design/components/search-bar/)
[image: cancel button does not work]

This is the link to the issue reproduction repo https://github.com/kvnlee777/antd-rn-issue

react-native version 0.61.4

ios simulator version 12.4

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Alert, View} from 'react-native';
import { SearchBar } from '@ant-design/react-native';


const SearchBarDemo = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');    
  const [showCancel, setShowCancel] = useState(true);

  const onChange = (currentValue) => {
    setValue(currentValue);
  }

  const clear = () => {
    setValue('');        
    setShowCancel(false);
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 30}}>           
      <SearchBar   
        value={value}
        placeholder="Search products, brands"
        onSubmit={value => Alert.alert(value)}              
        onCancel={clear}
        onChange={onChange}                  
        cancelText='Cancel'
        showCancelButton={showCancel}        
      />
    </View>
  );


};
export default SearchBarDemo;
```

Comment: change string to boolean for showCancel.

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping. Unfortunately the cancel button still cannot hide after changing to setShowCancel(false);

Comment: This is the link to the issue reproduction repo https://github.com/kvnlee777/antd-rn-issue

Answer (score 0):

You are using strings for true and false. The string `'false'` evaluates to `true`.

Replace `'true'` and `'false'` with `true` and `false`and it should work

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping. Unfortunately the cancel button still cannot hide after changing to setShowCancel(false);

Comment: This is the link to the issue reproduction repo https://github.com/kvnlee777/antd-rn-issue

Comment: If you click the cancel button in your app, it should disappear until you click the SearchBar again. I just tested it locally and it works for me. Could you provide an online example?

Comment: Hi, here is a video of the issue i encountered https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g7IMuJFvoLBRZwq9zd51bVB-nfnwWylb/view

Comment: Check this out: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-native-vdg1r

Comment: Hi, there is issue /node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view/withOrientation.js: Unexpected token, expected ";

Comment: Replace `"react-native-web": "0.11.x",` with `"react-native-web": "0.11.7",` in `package.json`

Comment: Hi, react-native-web is not in my package.json. Is it required for the search bar to run properly?

Comment: I tried yarn add react-native-web@0.11.7 but it still does not solve the issue